# I18n : missing translation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization

I'm using I18n and expo for localiztion , but i got that's error  [missing translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRbhn.png)

example of my code :

fr-FR.json :

```
  {
"account":"Compte",
"accountSub":"modifier adresse e-mail et le mot de passe",
"lang":"Langue",
"languageSub":"Choisissez votre langue",
"out":"Se déconnecter"
}
```

screen.js :

```
import en from './Language/en.json';
import fr from './Language/fr-FR.json';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { fr, en };

function Screen(){
  return(
     <Text style={styles.text} > {i18n.t('account')} </Text>
     <Text style={styles.desText} >   {i18n.t('accountSub')}</Text>
   )

}
```

Comment: `import fr from './Language/fr-FR.json';` But your json named `fr.json`?

Comment: no is  `fr-FR.json ` i do all right but don't work . I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try

```js
import * as fr from './Language/fr-FR.json';
```